# assigning properties to strings in text file

Tags: java, regex

Hopefully my explanation does me some justice. I am pretty new to java. I have a text file that looks like this

```
Java
The Java Tutorials
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/
Python
Tutorialspoint Java tutorials
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/
Perl
Tutorialspoint Perl tutorials
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/
```

I have properties for language name, website description, and website url. Right now, I just want to list the information from the text file exactly how it looks, but I need to assign those properties to them.

The problem I am getting is "index 1 is out of bounds for length 1"

```
try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Tutorials.txt"));

        while (in.readLine() != null) {
            TutorialWebsite tw = new TutorialWebsite();
            str = in.readLine();
            String[] fields = str.split("\\r?\\n");
            tw.setProgramLanguage(fields[0]);
            tw.setWebDescription(fields[1]);
            tw.setWebURL(fields[2]);
            System.out.println(tw);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I wanted to test something so i removed the new lines and put commas instead and made it str.split(",") which printed it out just fine, but im sure i would get points taken off it i changed the format.

Comment: Note: Using `in.readLine()` reads a line of text, so when you use `while (in.readLine() != null)`, you are actually reading a line but doing nothing with it... Is this intended behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

`readline` returns a "string containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters", so why are you trying to split each line on `"\\r?\\n"`?

Where is `str` declared? Why are you reading two lines for each iteration of the loop, and ignoring the first one?

I suggest you start from

```java
String str;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

and work from there.

The first `readline` gets the language, the second gets the description, and the third gets the url, and then the pattern repeats. There is nothing to stop you using `readline` three times for each iteration of the while loop.

Comment: I have declared it and that is where i started from. And nope, im just a really lost on this specific part. I tried it with scanner but and commented out fields[1] and [2] but then the output was "Java
null
null

The Java Tutorials
null
null" and so on... instead of only displaying the language name. Im sure there is a really simple solution

Comment: @angyeet There is no need to use `split`. Why not just e.g. `tw.setProgramLanguage(str);`?

Answer (score 0):

you can read all the file in a String like this

```
// try with resources, to make sure BufferedReader is closed safely
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Tutorials.txt"))) {
    
            //str will hold all the file contents
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line);
                str.append("\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Later you can split the string with

```
String[] fields = str.toString().split("[\\n\\r]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try it like this.

- allocate a List to hold the `TutorialWebsite` instances.
- use try with resources to open the file, read the lines, and trim any white space.
- put the lines in an array
- then iterate over the array, filling in the class instance
- the print the list.

The loop ensures the array length is a multiple of `nFields`, discarding any remainder. So if your total lines are not divisible by `nFields` you will not read the remainder of the file.  You would still have to adjust the setters if additional fields were added.

```
int nFields = 3;
List<TutorialWebsite> list = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("tutorials.txt"))) { 
    String[] lines = in.lines().map(String::trim).toArray(String[]::new);
     for (int i = 0; i < (lines.length/nFields)*nFields; i+=nFields) {
         TutorialWebsite tw = new TutorialWebsite();
         tw.setProgramLanguage(lines[i]);
         tw.setWebDescription(lines[i+1]);
         tw.setWebURL(lines[i+2]);
         list.add(tw);
     }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
    
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

A improvement would be to use a constructor and pass the strings to that when each instance is created.

And remember the file name as specified is relative to the directory in which the program is run.